# Display layers with output=embed on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on a lightweight WPF control for WPF using the output=embed urls for the maps I need.

I have 2 purposes for the map control one is to get the FSA boundaries for Canadian postal codes  and to show traffic conditions for a given address for a appointment tracking system for field agents 
ie
FSA https://maps.google.com/maps?q=m3j%20canada
Postal Code : https://maps.google.com/maps?q=M3A%201A3%20canada

which show up in a query to regular Google maps but once the output=embed is added to the url the boundaries disappear from the map

is there a way include these  in an embedded map or is this a restriction of embedded maps? if so is this functionality avail to the javascript api

Comment: This feature isn't available (neither in embedded maps , nor inside the Maps-Javascript-API)

Comment: =( guess ill have to build it using the main site and offset the render area